React Webpack Production deployment returns blank page
I am trying to deploy a react webapp application on production, but my UI returns a blank page with some errors in console.
Here are my configs:
Package.json:

  "name": "webpackreact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "option.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --progress --inline",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "download-file": "^0.1.5",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.0",
    "google-map-react": "^0.24.0",
    "jquery-file-download": "^1.4.6",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.1",
    "react-ckeditor-wrapper": "^1.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-file-download": "^0.3.4",
    "react-iframe": "^1.3.3",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-md-spinner": "^0.2.5",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.1.3",
    "react-overlay-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "react-popup": "^0.9.3",
    "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.10",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-rte": "^0.11.0",
    "react-search": "^2.0.5",
    "react-share": "^2.4.0",
    "react-social-buttons": "^1.0.8",
    "react-spinners": "^0.3.2",
    "react-tabs-component": "^1.1.3",
    "react-text-truncate": "^0.13.1",
    "react-texteditor": "^0.1.1",
    "react-word-limit": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "winterfell": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}


Dockerfile:
FROM node:12.1.0-slim as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./code/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install webpack@1.14.0 -g
COPY ./code ./
RUN webpack --mode production

FROM nginx:1.23
COPY --from=build /app/static /usr/share/nginx/html/static
COPY --from=build /app/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

default.conf:
server {
    listen       80; 
    server_name  _;   
    server_tokens off;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;

    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

My url throws blank page with the following in console:

I tried adding npm ls in Dockerfile which returned some package issues.
But my prodcution application was working perfectly fine when i had deployed it in host level before.

Please edit your post to remove the image and post the error text itself. Please do not post in images. Also please read the error, don't ignore it like you are now.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It seems like there might be a syntax error in your application source files.

I suggest checking the build process first. Run npm run build and see if there are any errors. If not, look at the browser console for any clues. Sometimes files might be missing or not configured properly in the deployment . Make sure your server is setup  to serve the react files correctly . check for the docker logs too . If everything looks fine there, consider reviewing configuration for any issues. Using debugging tools like Chrome DevTools can also provide insights into what's going wrong.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
